# Powershell Populate Listbox with Get-Aduser query results

Tags: wpf, powershell, wpf-controls

I am trying to populate a listbox in a Powershell created GUI based off of user input and am getting this error using this.

```
$CopyFromTextBox.Add_TextChanged({
$cmdlets = (Get-ADUser -Filter name -like "$($CopyFromTextBox.Text)" ) | Sort-Object 
$UserListBox.ItemsSource = $cmdlets
})
```

> Get-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'like'.

Below is an example of something like what I am trying to do but it actually works.

```
$InputBox.Add_TextChanged({
$cmdlets = @(Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet -Name ("{0}*" -f $InputBox.Text))
$listbox.itemsSource = $cmdlets
})
```

Comment: Your filter needs to be within brackets `{}`
`$cmdlets = (Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "$($CopyFromTextBox.Text)"} )` and don't think you need the pipe to Sort-Object

Answer (score 0):

The way that I was able to get this to work was by using this syntax

```
$query = $CopyFromTextBox.Text
$cmdlets = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$query*'")
```

Thanks for all of the help =)